# Limit number of nodes spawned by one Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

In my current setup of Jenkins, I have jobs that will spawn multiple nodes (and run them in parallel) for different types of tasks that require different container setups. Because of this sometimes when I run multiple jobs builds all the nodes are taken up. Is there a way to limit the number of nodes one job takes at the same time? (i.e if I set Jenkins to only take up 4 nodes at one time regardless of how many nodes a job needs; it will wait till a node is available)

Comment: Are nodes == Agents?  Can you elaborate a bit more? For example, how are you spawning Agents?

Comment: Yeah, so Nodes are agents. In this case we have several containers being spawn for separate sections of the job. So some parts of our builds require different container configurations and thats why we have it setup this way.

Comment: We are spawning nodes by getting a list of task that have the Node(some label to spawn the correct container) method and then use parallel on that list.